# determine finished activity result outisde activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

I am creating View component, which is able to open dialog for user input. I am able `startActivityForResult` inside Activity, but for some reasons I can't make component direct in activity class. Code is ease:

```
Context context = getContext();
if (context instanceof Activity)
  ((Activity)context).startActivityForResult(...);
else 
  context.startActivity(..) //fallback
```

How I can determine when activity is closed and catch result if possible?

Comment: try to improve the accepted answers rate and read fully the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make flag which in onCreate make false, and saved him to singltone or SharedPreferences, and in onDestroy this flag make true and save him. For catch result make receiver in current Activity on which send result from onDestroy. Or result work in onDestroy you can save to singltone or SharedPreference.
Thanks at time.

Comment: There isn't any more direct method?

Comment: I'm use this is method. Other I not know.